# How to execute a php file when calling a url with WebBrowser.Navigate()

Tags: c#, php, wordpress

Whenever I manually enter a URL in my browser and the URL references a WP page, any PHP file affiliated with that page will successfully execute the moment the page displays on the screen.  That's the norm for a WP site.  However, when I try to simulate that manual call using C#'s WebBrowser.Navigate() and the same URL, the PHP file doesn't get executed for some reason.  The PHP file executes only when I enter the URL manually in my browser.  Any thoughts?  Thanks for any help.

Vince Deegan

P.S.  Using Visual Studio 2010 Express and C#.

Comment: But in the code behind your browser, if your enter a url manually, its triggering `Navigate()` isnt it? Cant imagine why there should be a difference.

Comment: That's right.  My point exactly.